# Error(57,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here for creating stored procedures

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have created a `stored procedure` but while compiling it, I am getting error as

> Error(57,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Below is my query

```html
create or replace PROCEDURE NEIQC_DATA_DUMP_MST AS 
BEGIN

execute immediate 'truncate table TBL_NEIQC_WF_SITE_MST';

INSERT INTO TBL_NEIQC_WF_SITE_MST

(
    OBJECTID,
    SAP_ID,
    NETWORK_ENTITY_ID    ,
    SITE_NAME            ,
    SITE_ADDRESS         ,
    MAINTENANCEZONE_CODE ,
    INVENTORY_TYPE       ,
    TYPE_NAME            ,
    SITE_STATUS_CODE     , 
    NE_MODIFIED_DATE     ,
    NE_MODIFIED_BY       ,
    CREATED_DATE         ,
    CREATED_BY           ,
    STRUCTURE_NAME       ,
    RJ_CITY_CODE         ,
    RJ_R4G_STATE_CODE    ,
    RJ_DISTRICT_CODE     ,
    RJ_TALUK_CODE        ,
    RJ_JC_CODE           ,
    RJ_JIOPOINT_SAPCODE  ,
    RJ_COMPANY_CODE_1    ,
    RJ_COMPANY_CODE_2    
)

VALUES

(
    OBJECTID                      ,
    RJ_SAPID,                      
    RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID          ,
    RJ_SITE_NAME                  ,
    RJ_SITE_ADDRESS               ,
    RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE      ,
    '',
    TYPE_NAME                     ,
    'ACTIVE',
    RJ_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
    RJ_LAST_MODIFIED_BY ,
    SYSDATE,
    'SCHEDULER',
    STRUCTURE_NAME                ,
    RJ_CITY_CODE                  ,
    RJ_R4G_STATE_CODE             ,
    RJ_DISTRICT_CODE              ,
    RJ_TALUK_CODE                 ,
    RJ_JC_CODE                    ,
    RJ_JIOPOINT_SAPCODE           ,
    RJ_COMPANY_CODE_1             ,
    RJ_COMPANY_CODE_2          
);
 
COMMIT; 

END NEIQC_DATA_DUMP_MST;
```

please suggest what is wrong

Comment: What are you trying to insert? you truncate the table and what are the values you insert after?

Comment: @user7294900: values which I have mentioned under table `ne_structures`

Comment: where does the values come from between `values( ..)`? you should put there some values not column names

Comment: @hotfix: i want those values should be coming from `ne_structures` table of which columns i have mentioned

Comment: All the columns as `OBJECTID` exists in `ne_structures`?

Comment: @user7294900: yes all columns exist in `ne_structures`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your insert Statement should look like

```
INSERT INTO TBL_NEIQC_WF_SITE_MST

(
    OBJECTID,
    SAP_ID,
    NETWORK_ENTITY_ID    ,
    SITE_NAME            ,
    SITE_ADDRESS         ,
    MAINTENANCEZONE_CODE ,
    INVENTORY_TYPE       ,
    TYPE_NAME            ,
    SITE_STATUS_CODE     , 
    NE_MODIFIED_DATE     ,
    NE_MODIFIED_BY       ,
    CREATED_DATE         ,
    CREATED_BY           ,
    STRUCTURE_NAME       ,
    RJ_CITY_CODE         ,
    RJ_R4G_STATE_CODE    ,
    RJ_DISTRICT_CODE     ,
    RJ_TALUK_CODE        ,
    RJ_JC_CODE           ,
    RJ_JIOPOINT_SAPCODE  ,
    RJ_COMPANY_CODE_1    ,
    RJ_COMPANY_CODE_2    
)

select
    OBJECTID                      ,
    RJ_SAPID,                      
    RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID          ,
    RJ_SITE_NAME                  ,
    RJ_SITE_ADDRESS               ,
    RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE      ,
    '',
    TYPE_NAME                     ,
    'ACTIVE',
    RJ_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
    RJ_LAST_MODIFIED_BY ,
    SYSDATE,
    'SCHEDULER',
    STRUCTURE_NAME                ,
    RJ_CITY_CODE                  ,
    RJ_R4G_STATE_CODE             ,
    RJ_DISTRICT_CODE              ,
    RJ_TALUK_CODE                 ,
    RJ_JC_CODE                    ,
    RJ_JIOPOINT_SAPCODE           ,
    RJ_COMPANY_CODE_1             ,
    RJ_COMPANY_CODE_2          
  from ne_structures -- if this is your table
```

;

Comment: is commit required after insert ?

Comment: depends on, what you want and how you call a procedure. you can do a commit if you need

Comment: ok thanks hotfix for the quickest solution. If you dont mind can I ask one small question related to this.

Comment: you can, but only if it is a small one :)

Comment: See, I have one column as `Sap-ID` and in those values comes like this `I-KA-BVKL-ENB-9010`. So what I want is, if data in that column has word like `ENB` so the another column which is `INVENTORY_TYPE` should get updated with word as `SITE` .. can we achieve this ?

Comment: if you want to do that on insert you can use a `case` Expression. e.g. `case when RJ_SAPID like '%ENB%' then 'SITE' else 'What ever...' end`. add it on the right place in your `select`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194029/discussion-between-b-n-and-hotfix).